# Create a SQL Server database while deploying an RDS instance using Terraform

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I'm using Terraform  with the AWS provider (v3.37.0) to create an RDS instance:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
  
  identifier     = "my_db"
  engine         = "sqlserver-se"
  engine_version = "14.00.3401.7.v1"

  name           = null
  username       = "${somewhere/in/ssm}"
  password       = "${somewhere/in/ssm}"

}
```

I wish to create a database alongside this RDS instance, so the documentation (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.37.0/docs/resources/db_instance) states that I need to assign a value to the variable `name`, which I cannot, since the engine that I'm using (SQL Server) doesn't support that.

[image: SQL Server not supported for out-of-the-box database creation]

Is there another way to create that database inside this instance within Terraform?

I was thinking of using the `local-exec` provisioner or a community provider, but:

- For the `local-exec` provider, I don't know what I would put in the command. Would the following work, for example?

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {

  identifier     = "my_db"
  engine         = "sqlserver-se"
  engine_version = "14.00.3401.7.v1"

  name           = null
  username       = "${somewhere/in/ssm}"
  password       = "${somewhere/in/ssm}"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "USE master; CREATE DATABASE db-name"
  }

}
```

- For the community providers, I'm not really that trusting, but I could make leeway if they end up being my only option.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what I would put in the command

You need to use full `mssql-cli` command (or any other programming interface to mssql) which will execute on your computer and create your database. This means you have to have it installed first. For example, you can develop a python script which will connect and create your database. Then you invoke the python script from your `local-exec`.

Comment: The problem is going to be network access to the database. That `mssql-cli` command probably needs to run on a resource inside the VPC.